# Icons in Journey Builder Triggers?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I used to be able to set an icon for each trigger in JB but I don't see that option anymore. Was that removed?

Comment: Are you creating a trigger via the UI "Create Trigger" button when creating a new interaction?  Or are you creating a custom trigger (via your own app) and integrating it into Journey Builder via AppCenter?

Comment: using the UI, I believe I was able to add my own icon before.

Answer (score 2):

Adding icons for triggers created in the UI won't allow for adding an icon.  Icons can be added as a part of the custom trigger/activity configuration when creating your own custom triggers outside of ExactTarget.